# Cron Job Fails restarting Supervisor Process

Tags: cron, supervisord

I have a server running and using supervisor as process manager for my consumers.
Additionally I want to have a /etc/cron.d/restart_consumers file which executes daily.

The restart_consumers file looks like that:

```
#Ansible: daily restart of test_consumer
0 20 * * * root supervisorctl restart test_consumer
```

When I use `sudo supervisorctl restart test_consumer` it says stopping and starting and in the `supervisorctl status` output I can see an uptime of a few seconds.

When the Cron runs at 8 pm the running time of test_consumer is over a day. So it did not execute.

If I set cron log level to 1 I get the following entry in the log file which looks fine:

```
2016-03-09T20:00:01.377430+00:00 localhost /USR/SBIN/CRON[4762]: (root) CMD (supervisorctl restart test_consumer)
```

can anyone tell me how I get my cron to restart supervisor processes?

Restarting cron service did not help.

Thanks in advance and if you need any more information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my issue. The cron job needed the absolute path of supervisorctl to properly execute the task (probably an issue of the environment the cron is using on execution)

The working command is:

```
#Ansible: daily restart of test_consumer
0 20 * * * root /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart test_consumer
```

The consumer is now properly restarted by the cron.